# How to display data for user array in react using AG grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using API's to receive multiple row data from a particular user, my doubt is how one can display that data in react using AG-Grid format.

```
this.setState
                ({
                        
                        data: res.data,
                    
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                            headerName: " CreateDate", field: " CreateDate"
                          }, {
                            headerName: "Task Name", field: "TaskName"
                          }],
                
                          
                          rowData:[{
                          //facing errors while assigning these values

                                    TaskName : data.TaskName, 
                                    CreateDate : data[0].CreateDate    
                          }]   
                    })
```

Comment: What is the shape of the user object? Please also see [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-column-configuration)

Comment: hi aboli can you add more detail or can share working code/plunkr?

Comment: Hi Sandeep this is the example I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Aboli I am sharing stackblitz which will help you to do what you are trying to achieve.

I have assumed a lot about your data object since we dont know much about it. usually data should come in key value pair where keys matches to the field name which you have defined in your coldef object so that ag-grid can consume it directly.

But sometimes we need to sanitize data so that it matches with the way column field have been defined. feel free to ask more question and try to be a bit elaborative with code so that you can get solution faster.

here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-35z7n2?file=src/index.js) example.

Comment: hey, this was helpful Thanks!